# Making a cross domain request with authentication header

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

First of all, the server (not mine) returns the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

I'm trying to find out how to pass a request to the site with an authentication token. I'm running the code on a local apache server.

This is my code:

```
function get_data(){
    var url = '$URL';
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", url, true)
     if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
        var responseText = x.responseText;
        console.log(responseText)
        };
    x.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Bearer $TOKEN");
    x.withCredentials = true
    x.send()
}
```

The console returns:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load $URL. Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

While reading up on the documentation I saw that it is not allowed to manually set headers. When I removed `x.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Bearer $TOKEN");`I did get an answer from the server (an authentication error, obviously.) So how would I go about adding this information anyway to my request?

The headers returned by the server:

```
Request URL:$serverurl
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:$ipaddress
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html
Request Headers
view source
Accept:"*/*"
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authentication
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:$host
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/mv.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Please explain the meaning of "$URL".  Is this a token or placeholder for the real server url ?

Comment: similarly `$TOKEN` -

Comment: I replaced the url and token here for privacy reasons, they are placed correctly in my code. For what it's worth, I wrote the exact same script in Python without any problems.

Answer (score -1):

Before your actual GET request, the browser sends an OPTION request, to check what "options" it has for requesting (allowed methods, origins etc.).

Check the network tab for the options request (preflight) the browser sends. This request must have appropriate response headers e.g.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
```

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Since the server sends a 403 status header for the options request, it means the server doesnt handle the options request right, or simply sets 403 for your host as a measure of security. Unless that is changed, there is no way you can access that api via XHR.